# "Unable to start program" on Debug Immediately After Successful Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

When I try to run my first application with the debugger, I get a pop up which says:

Visual C__ 2008 Express Edition

This project is out of date:
       ProgName - Debug Win32
Would you like to build it?
[Yes[  [No]  [Cancel]
[ ] Do not show this dialog again?

I find this somewhat bothersome, because the very last thing that I did just before that was build the application.  And the build did complete successfully (immediately before I clicked on Start Debugging -- F5.)

The second time I pressed with wrong cilck on the Answer [No]  on the same msg 
Now, I can't compile my apps

What exactly does "do not show this dialog again" mean?

It sounds to me like its going to remember my answer and use the same answer every time this situation occurs in the future.

I did some stuffs like  "Clean Solution" then "Build Solution" then "Start Debugging" ,but the same problem

what's the solution ,how can I reset this message to make it work again .

Comment: This the boxDialog ,I clicked on No http://i39.tinypic.com/35lam29.png

Comment: Is it possible you are building the Release version of the code by default? This would explain why the Debug version is not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

2 mins after posting the problem ,I solve my problem and I'd like to share it now 
(in Tools->Options, "Projects and Solutions", "Build and Run". )
read carefully ,you can modify the values there 
Yups ;)